# vue test url fails on the clicked Button

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I wanted to create a simple Test on Vuejs.
The purpose is to click a router-link and prove that the pathname s correct.
Here is the Code:

```
    describe("Menu.vue", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(VueRouter);

  test("click on first routes to ./first", async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Menu, {
      localVue,
      router,
      stubs: {
        RouterLink: RouterLinkStub,

        First
      }
    });
    await wrapper.find("#testFirst").trigger("click");
    await Vue.nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.find("#testFirst").exists()).toBe(true);

    await flushPromises();
    expect(location.pathname).toBe("/first")
  });
});
```

The main component is a Menu.vue with router link id testFirst, the error comes from the last line where the expect fails.
The other component is named first.vue.
The first expect passes proving that the #testFirst exists. 
it expects"/first" and received "/" 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking location pathname you can test
`expect(wrapper.vm.$route.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({YOUR ROUTE})`

For this, you have to mock the $route push method that you can do in stubs while creating a wrapper for your componenet.

```
mocks: {
    $router:{
       push:jest.fn()
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the code [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-grothendieck-3kzm0)
the test is on the test folder